# Spring Boot JPA - User and Roles - Detached entity passed to persist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm not able to save a new user. Tried different approaches but always get the detached error. Has anyone faced this issue and fixed it? Tks in advance.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ie.fieldublin.domain.role.entity.Role
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:816)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:517)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:551)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:442)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:513)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:774)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:319)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy126.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:618)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:351)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)
    at org.sprin
```

[Database relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8iQL.png)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String username;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String password;

    private String country;

    private boolean accountNonExpired;

    private boolean accountNonLocked;

    private boolean credentialsNonExpired;

    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AuthProvider provider;

    private String providerId;

    private String imageUrl;

    private LocalDateTime dateCreated;

    private LocalDateTime dateEdited;

    public void addRole(Role role) {
        this.roles.add(role);
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

}


private User registerNewUser(OAuth2UserRequest oAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2UserInfo oAuth2UserInfo) {

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(oAuth2UserInfo.getEmail());
        user.setFirstname(oAuth2UserInfo.getName());
        user.setLastname(oAuth2UserInfo.getName());
        user.setPassword("");
        user.setCountry("BR");
        user.setAccountNonExpired(true);
        user.setAccountNonLocked(true);
        user.setCredentialsNonExpired(true);
        user.setEnabled(true);
        user.setProvider(AuthProvider.valueOf(oAuth2UserRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId()));
        user.setProviderId(oAuth2UserInfo.getId());
        user.setImageUrl(oAuth2UserInfo.getImageUrl());
        user.setDateCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
        user.setDateEdited(LocalDateTime.now());

        Role role = roleRepository.findById(2).orElse(null);

        user.addRole(role);

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Rof.png)

The only way I managed to make it work was by saving the user without setting a role, then after saving, adding the role and updating the user. Not sure this is correct.

I also added the mappedBy as suggested and changed the cascade from all to merge and persist.

```
    userRepository.save(user);
    user.addRole(roleRepository.findById(2).orElse(null));

    return userRepository.save(user);
```

Comment: Did you use Transaction in that operation?

Comment: Also try to add mappedBy to manytomany annotation

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez I have added the mappedBy and also changed the cascade to MERGE and PERSIST and suggested in other places. Still got the same error. The only way I managed to make it work was by saving the user, then adding the role and updating the user. I don't think this is practical at all. Not sure if this is because I'm using  JpaRepository for the save action.